# I'm getting a "concurrentModificationException" in java, but I'm not changing the list I'm iterating through

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I have an `ArrayList<List<String>>` that I'm trying to iterate through and print, however, I keep getting a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

My `ArrayList<List<String>>` represents lines of text, where each inner list is a line of a book and contains the strings that make up that line. I want to print the book out line by line. Here's the code that's causing the error:

```
public void print(ArrayList<List<String>> book) {
    if (book == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (List<String> lst : book) {
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : lst) {
            line.append(s + " ");
        }

       // delete the extra space at the end
       line.deleteCharAt(line.length() - 1);
       // print out the line
       System.out.println(line.toString());
    }

    // print out an extra newline to get ready for next input
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Note**: This print function takes as input the book, which is the output of another function. This other function is only used to parse the text file and put the words in the `ArrayList<List<String>>` format.

Comment: Any other threads accessing the data?

Comment: Isn't another thread producing the 'book'?

Comment: This printing code takes as input the "book", which is the output of another function.  This other function simply formats the data to be in the ArrayList<List<String>> type and then passes it to this printing function.

Answer (score 0):

A concurrent modification exception is raised when a list modification is done while at the same time iterating through the list.

Above you are just iterating through the list, but at the same time *elsewhere* someone alters the list.

Maybe a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) might be interesting. But several solutions are imaginable depending on your code.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your error :

you cannot edit a reference holds by an arraylist inside your for loop

```
    String s =  line;
    // delete the extra space at the end
      s.deleteCharAt(s.length() - 1);
```

Line is a string from your lst and Since strings are immutable it would be more suitable to declare a new String

Comment: I dont think there is any issue with it.

Comment: In the code snippet "line" is a StringBuilder created within the loop and appended with the value of the String s retrieved from the list. There is no editing done to any object in any list that I can see.